# How to tell if a switch is forwarding LLDP traffic

Tags: router, switch, traffic, lldp

How can I test if a switch is forwarding LLDP traffic?
(an engineer for my router's company said that most switches do, and can cause problems for their router, so I'm trying to chase this; another thread elsewhere said most switches do and cannot be configured to stop if they don't have such a setting, but that was just one answer)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

LLDP uses multicast destination addresses from the 01:80:C2 block that a switch compliant to IEEE 802.1D/802.1Q does not forward.

It's common for consumer-grade, unmanaged switches to forward that address all the same, but any managed or quality switch won't.

You can easily test a switch by connecting it in between an LLDP source and a capturing machine.